# Is iteration slower than linear code?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is iteration slower than linear code? Which one is preferable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176893/is-iteration-slower-than-linear-code-which-one-is-preferable)

I have a question in my mind from last many days, that while writing a code in ruby, is the linear code is faster and preferable than an iteration?

Let me have an example. There is a block of code for same functionality written in two different ways:

Way 1:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'tiger'].each do |pet_name|
  puts "I have many pets, one of them is #{pet_name}."
end
```

Way 2:

```
puts "I have many pets, one of them is dog."
puts "I have many pets, one of them is cat."
puts "I have many pets, one of them is tiger."
```

So, I want to know which one is better and preferable? As per my view, I think 2nd one will take less time and memory. But I want to confirm.